# Sitecore AB Testing with different components

Tags: experience-editor, personalization, content-testing

I know I am touching a bit of Personalization here. But I am trying to understand something pretty basic. 
I want to do A/B testing but not with a different set of content (data source) but two different rendering items.

**Like for example**, I want to AB test a hero image vs Video component.  The current Sitecore Out of box setting allows me only to choose different datasources not components.

One way I could think of is creating a custom wrapper component that is a combination of both hero and video component and then based on data source or type, chooses to display one. 
Do I have to customize this way or has someone been that path before with a better approach? 
**Sitecore Version 8.1**

Answer (score 1):

The approach you mention is suitable for when you want to include Rendering Parameters in your A/B test. For just switching between two components however, it is not necessary,

What you need to do, is enable `Personalize the presentation of the component`. This allows you to select between your Hero and Video components.

[image]

More information here: [Walkthrough: Personalizing components](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/personalization/walkthrough_personalizing_components)

(your specific use case under [this section](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/personalization/walkthrough_personalizing_components#_Personalize_the_layout))

Comment: Thanks @mark-cassidy.  Little confused here. This is personalization and would i be still be able to do variants. Like say 30% Rendering 1 vs 30% Rendering 2 and 40% Rendering 3? What you have mentioned here needs a logic to show right ? Like Geolocation or gender or something else ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; nor is it part of your original question. But when Sitecore conducts tests, it spreads exposure evenly across all options available. So if you have 3 variations, each of them get approximately 33% exposure. Which is also the only thing that makes sense; when you want to measure the most effective of the 3 at the end of the test.